# Listbox Refuses to update/List does not have matching types

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

In short, I wanted to create an updatable Listbox, which would update upon choosing an option from a ComboBox

```
<ListBox Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Lessons, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LessonText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        
                                     </StackPanel>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Image Source="{Binding LessonImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="auto" MaxWidth="400"/>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Changing a value of a variable Lesson fires an action, which fills an object list with elements

```
 public class LessonData : BaseViewModel
  {
    public int _lessonID;
    public string _lessonText;
    public byte[] _lessonImage;

    public int LessonID { get { return _lessonID; } set { _lessonID = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LessonID)); } }
    public string LessonText { get { return _lessonText; } set { _lessonText = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LessonText)); } }
    public byte[] LessonImage { get { return _lessonImage; } set { _lessonImage = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LessonImage)); } }
  }
public List<LessonData> editedLessons = new List<LessonData>();

 public List<LessonData> EditedLessons { get { return editedLessons; } set { editedLessons = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EditedLessons)); } }

 public string Lesson { get { return _lesson; } set { _lesson = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lesson));
        if (Lesson == "None")
        {
          EditedLessons.Clear();
          IsLessonBeingEdited = false;
        }
        else
        {
          EditedLessons = lessonRepository.Obtain_Lesson_Content(Lesson);
          foreach (LessonData p in EditedLessons) { Console.WriteLine(p.LessonID, p.LessonText, p.LessonImage); }
          IsLessonBeingEdited = true;
        }
      } }
```

Here is a function from a repository

```
public List<LessonData> Obtain_Lesson_Content(string Lesson)
    {
      List<LessonData> lc = new List<LessonData>();
      using (var connection = GetConnection())
      using (var command = new SqlCommand())
      {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Id_Lesson_Content, Lesson_Text, Lesson_Image FROM [Lesson_Content] WHERE Id_Lesson_Title = (SELECT Id_Lesson FROM [Lesson_Title] WHERE Lesson_Title = @title)";
        command.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Lesson;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            LessonData model = new LessonData();
            model.LessonID = (int)reader["Id_Lesson_Content"];
            model.LessonText = reader["Lesson_Text"].ToString();
            if (reader["Lesson_Image"] != System.DBNull.Value)
              model.LessonImage = (byte[])reader["Lesson_Image"];
            else
              model.LessonImage = null;
            lc.Add(model);
          }
          reader.NextResult();
        }
        foreach (LessonData p in lc) { Console.WriteLine(p.LessonID, p.LessonText, p.LessonImage); }
        return lc;
      }
    }
```

However every time I fire the function I meet with the errors thrown off (in that case it's loading two objects, one with and one without an image):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'System.Byte[]' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=LessonImage; DataItem='LessonData' (HashCode=2419756); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Byte[]' BindingExpression:Path=LessonImage; DataItem='LessonData' (HashCode=2419756); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'System.Byte[]' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=LessonImage; DataItem='LessonData' (HashCode=10026414); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

But to me the weirdest part is that trying to write all the list objects in a console throws these three errors:

- can't convert from int to char[],
- from string to int
- from byte[] to int

  foreach (LessonData p in lc) { Console.WriteLine(p.LessonID, p.LessonText, p.LessonImage); }

Like, why does it even happen? I had looked at my other identical/similar functions which work in the same fashion and none of them throws such compilation errors. On top of that, when I change order of object elements by putting LessonID as the last, it does not display errors, (however the only item displayed is LessonText).

Whatever is the reason, I believe it is hidden behind that error with reading the list.

Comment: As a note, the expression `else model.LessonImage = null;` is redundant, `null` is the default value.

Comment: I know, I just happen to set variables as null when I need to automatically,without even paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the error message is the binding expression

```
Source="{Binding LessonImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

While there is a built-in automatic type conversion from `string`, `Uri` and `byte[]` to `ImageSource` (the type of the `Source` property) there is no automatic conversion back to those types (except string) which would be required for a `TwoWay` Binding.

A `TwoWay` Binding of the `Source` property is pointless in the first place, because an Image element never changes that property by itself. The same applies to the `Text` property binding of the TextBlock element.

So just use a `OneWay` Binding, where setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` is also pointless, because it affects only `TwoWay` and `OneWayToSource` Bindings.

```
Source="{Binding LessonImage}"
```

---

Besides that, the source property of the `ItemsSource` binding must be a collection that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, e.g. an ObservableCollection instead of a List:

The property should also be readonly:

```
public ObservableCollection<LessonData> EditedLessons { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<Lesson>();
```

The Binding is also not TwoWay, but should just be

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EditedLessons}" ...>
```

because a ListBox never actively changes the value of its `ItemsSource` property. This does not mean that the collection referenced by the property can't change.

Comment: Still the same issue, ListBox is not being updated in the application.

However I'd also like to point out that I used this expression for a reason, since I wanted the elements of the list to be updatable, text and image alike. After I asked this question I googled a bit and figured out that setting up a converter should do a job and keep the functionality I desire.

Comment: Still this is the exact reason for the binding error you were observing. Whether there was a reason for a TwoWay Binding is not clear from your question. There is nothing in the code you provided that would show or even indicate how your "updatable" ListBox is supposed to work. If there is an additional element that performs the "update" part like the ComboBox you are mentioning, this element would operate on the view model, not on the ListBox, so that TwoWay Bindings in the ItemTemplate are still pointless.

Comment: See the edited answer for the other error.

Comment: applied your suggestions and now it's all working like a charm, thank you!